# PHP difference between \n and just new line in sprintf and writing files

Tags: php, linux

I'm developing in LAPM environment.
What is difference between "\n", just new line?

There are several examples.

> example 1

```
$content = sprintf("alias=%s
alias2=%s
alias3=%s", "apple", "banana", "cosmos");
```

> example 2

```
$content = sprintf("alias=%s\nalias2=%s\nalias3=%s", "apple", "banana", "cosmos");
```

And when i create a file with this content,

> result of example 1

```
alias=appler
alias2=banana
alias3=cosmos
```

> result of example 2

```
alias=apple
alias2=banana
alias3=cosmos
```

What is the **"r" of alias=appler** in **result of example 1?**

What is the difference between "\n" and new line of enter key action?

I'm sorry for being not good at English.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is basically no difference between `\n` and newline generated by [ENTER] key, but only until you are running on a Linux-based text-editor or IDE. In windows environment the [ENTER] key is represented by `\r\n`.

I have no explanation for that *r* in the first example, there must be some problem in the way you are executing or showing it. Is there any other code? (For example the file-writing one)